# Draw Circle Programmatically in Android

Tags: android

I am creating an application where in a fragment I should draw a circle.. The circle must repeat based on a number. I mean, A number will be received from server and some string..So the circle should be created for the number of times the number I received and on each circle when clicked I should be able to toast the string I received.

For Example I will be getting number 3 and 3 strings(a,b,c).
In Fragment it should automatically create 3 circles with each string name on it respectively. 
I am able to create a single circle from text view from xml

circle code:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
            android:shadowRadius="10.0"
            android:text="STOP"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/carddemo1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
```

> 1st image is what I get while I should be getting like the 2nd image as defined above.

[image: Circle I Created Looks Like]
[image]

Comment: you can create text view programatically with circle background

Comment: You can create all your TextViews once. Then play with their **visibility** at run time.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i got the Question but you have to create multiple Text Views for 3 Circles:

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
            android:shadowRadius="10.0"
            android:text="STOP"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/carddemo1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />


    <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
            android:shadowRadius="10.0"
            android:text="STOP"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/carddemo1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />


    <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
            android:shadowRadius="10.0"
            android:text="STOP"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/carddemo1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />



    <TextView
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
            android:shadowRadius="10.0"
            android:text="STOP"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/carddemo1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />
```

Of course add different Coordinates.

Comment: I can do that.. But need to create in dynamically.. Number will be determined from activity . And that much textview should be created.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shape drawable that you already have

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myViewGroupId);
```

run a loop for the counter you are getting

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myShape));
        textView.setText("this is my text from the server");
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
    }
```